# Bash: save clipboard to a file with line breaks like it was copied

Tags: macos, bash, vim

I'm on OS X server try to copy a formatted text from vim and then would like to save it to another file via bash. I want my new file looks like the text that was copied into vim to clipboard - with line breaks, space indentations... instead I get a plain text in one line.

I do this, after copping: `` echo `pbpaste` > file.txt ``

Is there a way to save formatted text to the new file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to echo.

```
pbpaste > file.txt
```

The problem was caused by the lack of quotation:

```
echo `echo "x  x"`    #x x
echo "`echo "x  x"`"  #x  x
```

Comment: Thank you for help and explanations! It's really help me!

Answer (score 2):

wrap it in double quotes

```
echo "`pbpaste`" > file.txt
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! I've scoured all the internet but didn't find this simple solution!